# MySQL search with Unique column

Tags: mysql, search

I have a simple and quick question. I have a users table in mysql having millions of users. username column inside this table has "unique" index created.

Now I wanted to search a particular user from this table and I write like this:

```
SELECT user_id FROM tbl_user WHERE username LIKE 'someuser%'
```

But this does not give accurate result and I had to put % on both sides to make it work, like this:

```
SELECT user_id FROM tbl_user WHERE username LIKE '%someuser%'
```

This makes the search very slow since it does not utilize the index.
Any suggestion how to make it super fast? Should I apply Fulltext index? Will that be okay to have both unique and fulltext applied on the same column?

Below is the table structure

> `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS`tbl_user`(`
>   user_id`int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,`
>   username`varchar(50) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,`
>   password`varchar(40) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,`
>   active`tinyint(4) NOT NULL default '1',`
>   firstname`varchar(20) collate utf8_unicode_ci default NULL,`
>   lastname`varchar(20) collate utf8_unicode_ci default NULL,`
>   email`varchar(50) collate utf8_unicode_ci default NULL,
>     PRIMARY KEY  (`user_id`),
>     UNIQUE KEY`username`(`username`)
>   ) ENGINE=InnoDB;`

---

I think FullText index will work fine. But if I use OR to perform FullText on another column within same query (example below), it does not use index. It use index only when there is only one Full text search condition in where clause.

```
> WHERE MATCH(username) AGAINST ('keyword') OR MATCH(displayname) AGAINST('keyword')
```

Any ideas?

Comment: why do you search `LIKE` if value is unique in most cases you should search for `username = yourname`

Comment: could you post `CREATE TABLE` statement please?

Comment: @Alex: my first thought would be to search on the first part of the name - maybe querying as the user types the name into a field.

Comment: How do you mean "does not give accurate result" ?

Comment: @Alex, support people uses a keyword to search for user. They do not know the exact username. For example, for diana@someemail.com, they may search for "diana" only. So we cannot use username = yourname.

Comment: @PaulF, with diana@someemail.com as an example user, "LIKE 'diana%'" gives good results but if someone uses "someemail" as search keyword, then "LIKE 'someone%'" does not give any result.

Comment: `usernamevarchar(200)` really? `firstnamevarchar(300)` what country do you target your application? in which universe first name could be 300 characters? how do you get your passport in that country?

Comment: @Alex: looks like the username is a unique identifier like an email address - so maybe too long but not necessarily if it is to be unique. First & last names though !!!

Comment: If searching on email domains is common, then denormalise your data and have a separate email domain field created, populated and indexed. You may even want to consider having a separate lookup table with your userids and lookup columns.

Comment: if you really plan to keep those huge numbers of limit for username credentials, you should probably really set fulltext indexes on those columns.

Comment: If the tables are MyISAM then you could look at Full Text Searching : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: @PaulF looks like badly designed table structure....

Comment: @Alex: I just spotted the email address can be up to 300 chars as well, so not always possible to use that as a 200 char username

Comment: If email domains is your use case, I suggest reconsidering the requirement.  The semantics of a domain are that MANY users have accounts there.

Comment: Thanks for all the input so far. 300 varchar for firstname/lastname is no doubt too huge. The database was created few years back by someone else not me :) So ignoring the firstname/lastname length, any suggestion how to improve search by username only ?

Comment: I don't think fulltext indexes will help you because [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-boolean.html) appears to suggest you can only use wildcard matching on the end of words and not the start.

Comment: I wonder how people with millions of user perform user search? I have reduce the column length for this question only.
Any other way, any suggestion to re-structure the table to make search super fast?